# Как в компоненте ListBox изменить вид списка элементов?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Чтобы при нажати или наведении мышкой на элемент выделялась вся строка, а не только название (смотрим скрин). (Visual Studio 2010, C#.)

[image: снимок]

P.S. Заранее спасибо и с Новым годом!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это возможно при использовании `ListView`, в котором присутствует свойство [`FullRowSelect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.fullrowselect.aspx).

Comment: Премного благодарен!